# Thread 1 "my_app" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault when accessing API from another library

Tags: c++, boost, segmentation-fault

From my C++ application my_app compiled using G++, I am invoking several API's from another shared library tool.so (tool.so also developed using C++). Each reference of API call from tool.so I am getting the below segmentation fault from the GDB.

```
Thread 1 "my_app" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff61406cd in boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code\*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.65.1
```

problem seem to be boost version mismatch. myapp needs boost 1.65 but tool.so compiled using boost 1.55. I am statically linking both and get segmentation error. I modified the CmakeList.txt, so that it dynamically links my_app, tool. but still I get the same segmentation error. any suggestion?

CmakeLists.txt
add_library(tool SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(tool PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${TOOL_LIB_DIR}/tool.so)
target_link_libraries(my_app PRIVATE tool)

```
Thread 1 "my_app" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff61406cd in boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code\*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.65.1
```

```
    int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
    {
    ..  
    if(TOOL_Initialize() == TOOL_FAIL)    ----> Call 1 
    {
      std::cout <<" failed to initialize.\n";
    } 
    ..
    ..
    ..
    
    if(TOOL_DEVICE_GetCount(DEVICE_TYPE)!= TOOL_SUCCESS)--> call 2
    { 
     cout << "Get CPU count API failed exiting" << endl ; 
    }
}
```

Getting segmentation fault in call 1, if comment out call 1 then getting in call 2 wherever I am invoking lib call

Comment: Lot of possibilities. Use the back trace to work backwards to your code and make sure you are using the library correctly. Also remember that you could have a bug anywhere in your code that mortally wounds the program, but leaves it alive enough to finally collapse somewhere totally innocent.

Comment: It may not be a different version of boost or even boost related. However you can check to make sure that your application was using the same version of boost.

Comment: And the same compilation flags

Comment: my application main.cpp uses boost version 1.65.1 but API calls used in main.cpp from tool.so uses boost version 1.55

Comment: problem seem to be boost version mismatch. my_app needs boost 1.65 but the library I  tool.so compiled using boost 1.55. I am statically linking my_app and tool.so and get segmentation error at the I invoke a API call from tool.so . I modified the CmakeList.txt, so that it dynamically links my_app, tool. but still I get the same segmentation error. any suggestion? CmakeLists.txt add_library(tool SHARED IMPORTED) set_target_properties(tool PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${TOOL_LIB_DIR}/tool.so) target_link_libraries(my_app PRIVATE tool)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked by adding this option,
**target_link_options(my_app PUBLIC "LINKER:/home/fkamalmu/toollib_1_7_8/lib/linux/tool.so")** instead of below way of
linking
add_library(tool SHARED IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(tool PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${TOOL_LIB_DIR}/tool.so)

target_link_libraries(my_app PRIVATE tool)